# C Array elements all changing to the same value

Tags: arrays, c, file-io, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm trying to populate an array of names using an input file, however the elements of my array all end up turning into the same value and I'm unsure why.

```
    char* names[name_count];

    for (int i = 0; i < name_count; i++) {
        names[i] = fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, input_fp);
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            puts(names[j]);
        }
    }
```

The first line of the input file specifies how many names there are, and the assignment specified that we won't need to use dynamically allocated memory so I'm using a variable-sized array.

If I had 5 names and the last one was Ed, the result at the end of the for loop would be my array storing Ed in all the spots instead of Ed in the last spot and the rest of the names before it.

Comment: You need to change char* names[name_count] to something that can actually store strings, such as char names[max_string_length][name_count] and then use strcpy to copy each string into the array. With your current code, the string is copied into buffer, but not into names array.

Comment: To clarify, buffer is a char array I use to store each line of the file with a length of 100, which is what I set the value I set MAX_LINE_LENGTH to as well.

Comment: @SvenNilsson `strcpy` is not required. You can simply read the strings directly to `names[i]` with the 2D array.

Comment: Yeah that's right, if he wants to ditch "buffer" completely, fgets(names[i], MAX_LINE_LENGTH, input_fp); will suffice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fgets()` function](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) returns the `buffer` passed.

You are reusing the `buffer`, so the elements are set to the same pointers and the contents are overwritten.

You should **copy the strings** to retain the contents.

Using functions from `stdlib.h` (`malloc`) and `string.h` (`strcpy`):

```c
        fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, input_fp);
        names[j] = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1); /* +1 for the terminating null character */
        if (names[j] == NULL) exit(99); /* check for allocation failure */
        strcpy(names[j], buffer);
```

Or using a POSIX function (not in the C standard before C23) in `string.h`:

```c
        names[i] = strdup(fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, input_fp));
```

Comment: Thanks! The last suggestion was exactly what I needed, while It'd be easier doing it by allocating memory and using strcpy as I mentioned in the original post the assignment says that memory allocation isn't needed so I'd like to stick to that.

Comment: Was basically trying to find a way to duplicate the string from buffer as I kind of guess it had to do with it pointing towards buffer's location, didn't know how though. Thank you again!